# How to force object key name in array

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

I am using YAML to mark up some formulas and using JSON schema to provide a reference schema. 
An example of the YAML might be:

```
formula: # equates to '5 + (3 - 2)'
  add:
    - 5
    - subtract: [3, 2]
```

While I have figured out how to make the immediate child object of the formula (`"add"` in this example) have the right key name and type (using a `"oneOf"`array of `"required"`s). I am not sure how to ensure that object of an array (`"subtract"`) likewise use specific key names.

So far, I can ensure the type using the following. But with this method, as long as the object used matches the subtract *type*, it is allowed any key name, it is not restricted to `subtract`:

```
"definitions: {
    "add": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/value"}, # value type is an integer which allows for the shown scalar array elements
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract" }
                // other operation types
            ]
        }
    },
    "subtract": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "maxItems": 2,
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/value"},
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/add" }
                // other operation types
            ]
        }
    }
    // other operation types
}
```

How can I introduce a restriction such that the keys of objects in the array match specific names, while still also allowing scalar elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was extending the idea of I already used with the '`"oneOf"`array of `"required"`, adding an `"anyOf"`.

Thus, an operator schema is now:

```
"definitions": {
    "add": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "items": {
            "anyOf": [
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/literal" }, // equates to a simple YAML scalar
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/constant" },
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/variable" },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "oneOf": [
                        { "required": ["add"] },
                        { "required": ["subtract"] }
                        // more operator names
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "add": { "$ref": "#/definitions/add" },
                        "subtract": { "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract" }
                        // more operator type references
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    // more definitions
}
```

This can be refactored to something that applies more easily across different operators like so:

```
"definitions": {
    "operands": {
        "literal": { "type": "number" }, // equates to a simple YAML scalar
        "constant": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "value": { "type": "number" }
            },
            "required": [ "value" ]
        },
        "variable": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": { type": "string" },
                "type": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": [ "name", "type" ]
        }
    }
    "operators": {
        "add": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 2,
            "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/anyOperandsOrOperators" }
        },
        "subtract": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 2,
            "maxItems": 2,
            "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/anyOperandsOrOperators" }
        }
        // more operator types
    },
    "anyOperator": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            { "required": ["add"] },
            { "required": ["subtract"] }
            // more operator names
        ],
        "properties": {
            "add": { "$ref": "#/definitions/operators/add" },
            "subtract": { "$ref": "#/definitions/operators/subtract" }
            // more operator type references
        }
    },
    "anyOperandsOrOperators":
    {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/operands/literal" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/operands/constant" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/operands/variable" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/anyOperator"}
        ]
    }
}
```

And this means the YAML for an operator can look as follows

```
                    \/mapping   \/mapping
add:[ 5, subtract:[ *constantA, *variableB ] ]
scalar^  ^mapping with specific name
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is recursive references.

By creating a new definition which is `oneOf` the operations and `value`, which then allow items which then reference back to the new definition, you have recursive references.

```
"definitions: {
    "add": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/operations_or_values"},
    },
    "subtract": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 2,
        "maxItems": 2,
        "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/operations_or_values"},
    }
    // other operation types
    "operations_or_values": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#definitions/add" },
        { "$ref": "#definitions/subtract" },
        { "$ref": "#definitions/value" },                 # value type is an integer which allows for the shown scalar array elements
        { "$ref": "#definitions/[OTHERS]" },
      ]
    }
}
```

I haven't had time to test this, but I believe it will be, or be close to, what you need. Let me know if it doesn't work. I may not have full understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

What a fascinating problem! This remarkably concise schema can express any expression.

```
{
  "type": ["object", "number"],
  "propertyNames": { "enum": ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"] },
  "patternProperties": {
    ".*": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 2,
      "items": { "$ref": "#" }
    }
  }
}
```